# Alertmanager email route

Tags: prometheus-alertmanager

I am trying  configure the "route" of alertmanager, below is my configuration:

```
route:
  group_by: ['instance']
  group_wait: 30s
  group_interval: 5m
  repeat_interval: 7m
  receiver: pager
  routes:
  - match:
      severity: critical
      receiver: email
  - match_re:
      severity: ^(warning|critical)$
      receiver: support_team

receivers:
- name: 'email'
  email_configs:
  - to: 'xxxxxx@xx.com'
- name: 'support_team'
  email_configs:
  - to: 'xxxxxx@xx.com'
- name: 'pager'
  email_configs:
  - to: 'alert-pager@example.com'
```

Now the e-mail can only be send to the default receiver "pager", will not further route to the custom one.

Answer (score 0):

You need this line for each route when want alerts to be routed to the other ones.

```yaml
continue: true
```

e.g.

```yaml
route:
  group_by: ['instance']
  group_wait: 30s
  group_interval: 5m
  repeat_interval: 7m
  receiver: pager
  routes:
  - match:
      severity: critical
    receiver: email
    continue: true
  - match_re:
      severity: ^(warning|critical)$
    receiver: support_team
    continue: true

receivers:
- name: 'email'
  email_configs:
  - to: 'xxxxxx@xx.com'
- name: 'support_team'
  email_configs:
  - to: 'xxxxxx@xx.com'
- name: 'pager'
  email_configs:
  - to: 'alert-pager@example.com'
```

btw. imho receiver should be at the same level as match in yaml structure.